# Variable won't update immediately after async operation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await

I am fetching count of documents from Firestore. Because of the query limitations, I had to create a loop to make it work. Here's the code -

```
for (List targetLocations in targetLocationsList) {
    AggregateQuerySnapshot? targetUsersSnapshot;

    if (_selectedTargetGender == 'both') {
      targetUsersSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('dob', isLessThanOrEqualTo: birthDateLower)
          .where('dob', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: birthDateUpper)
          .where('taluka', whereIn: targetLocations)
          .count()
          .get();
    } else {
      targetUsersSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('dob', isLessThanOrEqualTo: birthDateLower)
          .where('dob', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: birthDateUpper)
          .where('gender', isEqualTo: _selectedTargetGender)
          .where('taluka', whereIn: targetLocations)
          .count()
          .get();
    }

    targetUsersCount += targetUsersSnapshot.count;
}

setState(() {
  _targetUsersCount = targetUsersCount;
});
```

In the `setState` at the bottom, I expect the value of `targetUsersCount` to be from the latest run. But it always shows the value from the last execution. That is, I have to execute it twice to get the correct value. What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the root of the issue by systematically removing each element. I found that somehow if-else is the culprit here. Though I am not entirely sure why. I had to move the actual query out of the if-else block.

I modified the code and now it is working as expected.

```
for (List targetLocations in targetLocationsList) {
    Query<Map<String, dynamic>>? targetUsersQuery;

    if (_selectedTargetGender == 'both') {
      targetUsersQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('dob', isLessThanOrEqualTo: birthDateLower)
          .where('dob', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: birthDateUpper)
          .where('taluka', whereIn: targetLocations);
    } else {
      targetUsersQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('dob', isLessThanOrEqualTo: birthDateLower)
          .where('dob', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: birthDateUpper)
          .where('gender', isEqualTo: _selectedTargetGender)
          .where('taluka', whereIn: targetLocations);
    }

    AggregateQuerySnapshot targetUsersSnapshot =
        await targetUsersQuery.count().get();
    targetUsersCount += targetUsersSnapshot.count;
}

setState(() {
  _targetUsersCount = targetUsersCount;
});
```